# Abstract types can only be instantiated with additional type information - OSGI

Tags: inheritance, interface, jackson, mapping, osgi

I am using MongoJack on a OSGI Stack. Below is the exception I am getting:

> set 29, 2015 3:12:59 PM com.mongodb.DBPortPool gotError ADVERTÊNCIA:
>   emptying DBPortPool to localhost/127.0.0.1:27017 b/c of error
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map. JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of api.Book, problem: abstract types can only be instantiated
>   with additional type information  at [Source:
>   de.undercouch.bson4jackson.io.LittleEndianInputStream@4fe0026c; pos:
>   0]
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.instantiationException(StdDeserializationContext.java:233)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:60)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2704)
>       at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1315)
>       at net.vz.mongodb.jackson.internal.stream.JacksonDBDecoder.decode(JacksonDBDecoder.java:62)
>       at com.mongodb.Response.(Response.java:83)
>       at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:142)
>       at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:92)
>       at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:244)
>       at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:216)
>       at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:288)
>       at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:273)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:368)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:459)
>       at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:484)
>       at net.vz.mongodb.jackson.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:315)
>       at mongo.BookInventoryMongo.listBooks(BookInventoryMongo.java:44)
>       at mongo.BookInventoryMongo.start(BookInventoryMongo.java:58)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.InvocationUtil.invokeMethod(InvocationUtil.java:111)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.InvocationUtil.invokeCallbackMethod(InvocationUtil.java:66)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.invokeCallbackMethod(ComponentImpl.java:688)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.invoke(ComponentImpl.java:679)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.bindService(ComponentImpl.java:624)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.access$400(ComponentImpl.java:52)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl$7.run(ComponentImpl.java:181)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor$1.run(SerialExecutor.java:47)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.scheduleNext(SerialExecutor.java:84)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.access$000(SerialExecutor.java:33)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor$1.run(SerialExecutor.java:50)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.scheduleNext(SerialExecutor.java:84)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.access$000(SerialExecutor.java:33)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor$1.run(SerialExecutor.java:50)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.scheduleNext(SerialExecutor.java:84)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.SerialExecutor.execute(SerialExecutor.java:68)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.calculateStateChanges(ComponentImpl.java:231)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.impl.ComponentImpl.start(ComponentImpl.java:399)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyManager.add(DependencyManager.java:169)
>       at mongo.Activator.init(Activator.java:28)
>       at org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyActivatorBase.start(DependencyActivatorBase.java:76)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2154)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2072)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:976)
>       at aQute.launcher.Launcher.update(Launcher.java:457)
>       at aQute.launcher.Launcher$1.run(Launcher.java:194)
>       at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
>       at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
>
> WARNING: Invocation of 'start' failed.
>   (com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: Read operation to server
>   localhost/127.0.0.1:27017 failed on database test_booksDB)

Below the code:

```
**api bundle**

package api;
public interface Book {
    public String getBookName();
    public void setBookName(String name);
}

package api;
import java.util.List;

public interface BookInventory {
    public void addBook(Book book);
    public List<Book> listBooks();
}



**mongo bundle**

package mongo;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonCreator;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import api.Book;

public class BookMongo implements Book{

    private String _id;
    private String bookName;

    public BookMongo() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@JsonCreator
    public BookMongo(@JsonProperty ("id") String _id, @JsonProperty     ("bName") String bookName) {
    super();
    this._id = _id;
    this.bookName = bookName;
}


@JsonProperty("id")
public String get_id() {
    return _id;
}

public void set_id(String _id) {
    this._id = _id;
}

@Override
@JsonProperty("bName")
public String getBookName() {
    return bookName;
}

@Override
public void setBookName(String name) {
    this.bookName = name;

}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "BookMongo [_id=" + _id + ", bookName=" + bookName + "]";
}

}


package mongo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import net.vz.mongodb.jackson.DBCursor;
import net.vz.mongodb.jackson.JacksonDBCollection;
import org.amdatu.mongo.MongoDBService;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonDeserialize;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import api.Book;
import api.BookInventory;

public class BookInventoryMongo implements BookInventory{

private volatile MongoDBService mongoDBService;

@Override
public void addBook(Book book) {

    DBCollection collection =   mongoDBService.getDB().getCollection("booksColl");
    JacksonDBCollection<Book, Object> books =     JacksonDBCollection.wrap(collection, Book.class);
    addBook
    books.save(book);

}

@Override
@JsonDeserialize(contentAs=BookMongo.class)   
public List<Book> listBooks() {


    DBCollection collection = mongoDBService.getDB().getCollection("booksColl");
    JacksonDBCollection<Book, Object> books = JacksonDBCollection.wrap(collection, Book.class);

    DBCursor<Book> cursor = books.find();

    List<Book> result = new ArrayList<Book>();
    while (cursor.hasNext()) {
        result.add(cursor.next());
    }

    return result;

}

//The start method is the entry point for the app.
public void start(){   

    Book bm = new BookMongo("5","The walking dead");
    addBook(bm);
    System.out.println("****Attention***");
    System.out.println("New book added to mongo");
    System.out.println(listBooks().toString());
    }

}


package mongo;

import java.util.Properties;
import org.amdatu.mongo.MongoDBService;
import org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyActivatorBase;
import org.apache.felix.dm.DependencyManager;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import api.BookInventory;

public class Activator extends DependencyActivatorBase{

@Override
public void destroy(BundleContext arg0, DependencyManager arg1)
        throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void init(BundleContext arg0, DependencyManager dm)
        throws Exception {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("persistent", true);

dm.add(createComponent()
        .setInterface(BookInventory.class.getName(), props)
        .setImplementation(BookInventoryMongo.class)
        .add(createServiceDependency()
                .setService(MongoDBService.class).
                setRequired(true)));

    }

}
```

It is clear to me that the problem is due to the impossibility of mongo-jackson-mapper to read from the bank. It cannot instantiate the `Book.class` once it is an interface.

Unfortunately, annotating any of the api interfaces is not an option  otherwise it would broke modularity.

In previous research trying to solve it, I thought MixIns would be the more suitable option here, however it didn't work at all. I might be doing something wrong. Is there any option to solve this? By the way, the `addBook` method in `BookInventoryMongo` works fine.